# asp mvc 404 when + in url

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing, http-status-code-404, asp.net-mvc

I have problem with **asp mvc 3** application. When I put the `+` character in a url I always get a **404 error**. All requests are ajax get request.

If I make this request **Test/Details/+** I get **404: Test/Details/+**

This is request in fiddler: `GET /Test%2FDetails%2F%2B?t=1318678807718 HTTP/1.1`

Here are routes.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "PagingTwoTest", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{tag}/p{currentPage}/p{secCurrentPage}/{*term}", // URL with parameters
    new { secCurrentPage = UrlParameter.Optional, term = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
    new { currentPage = "\\d+", secCurrentPage = "\\d+" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "PagingTwo", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/p{currentPage}/p{secCurrentPage}/{*term}", // URL with parameters
    new { secCurrentPage = UrlParameter.Optional, term = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
    new { currentPage = "\\d+", secCurrentPage = "\\d+" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Paging", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/p{currentPage}/{*term}", // URL with parameters
    new { term = UrlParameter.Optional }, // Parameter defaults
    new { currentPage = "\\d+" }
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);

routes.MapRoute(
    "DefaultName", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{*id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your constraints you are not considering when someone enters a string you allways request a digit, so I think you can try with:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "TestDetails", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { 
        controller = "Test", 
        action = "Details", 
        id = UrlParameter.Optional 
    }
);
```

So in your TestController you can request a string:

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    ....
    ....

    public ActionResult Details(string? id) //So you can verify if is null
    {
        ViewData["variable"] = id;
        return View();
    }
    ....
    ....
}
```

And in your `Details.aspx` you can put something like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" 
    MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    Title, what you want
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <p> Blah, blah, blah, you request this: <%: ViewData["variable"] %> </p>
</asp:Content>
```